# AndroidStudio 2.1.2: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android-studio-2.1

MainActivity.java contains:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        display(1);
    }

    private void display(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
    }
}
```

What is the reason for the compile error?

gradle.build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.justjava"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}

I have already tried: `clean/rebuild project`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its issues around your compileSdkVersion and buildToolVersion change it in your gradle file and you should be fine.
  
  `compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'`

you can as well update your  `targetSdkVersion` to 24

Comment: I have added the gradle.build above in the question. Those have already been incorporated. No luck, yet.

Comment: but your buildToolVersion is 24.0.1 and not 24.0.0

Comment: I changed to 24.0.0 - resynced gradle - run the program again: Error:(21, 25) error: package R does not exist AND Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: There was an error in the package statement. This is resolved. Thanks!